# Enable to swipe only in certain widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have see a PageView in Flutter which does the right job of swiping between different pages. But we can swipe anywhere on the current page to go left or right. But my question is to swipe only in certain area to go left and right. How to implement that?

[image]

In the above image, I only want to swipe in the blue container to go left or right.

Comment: you may be able to achieve that using [Flutter_Swipper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the solution for the above problem with the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AccountScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class AccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AccountScreenState createState() => _AccountScreenState();
}

class _AccountScreenState extends State<AccountScreen> {
  PageController _bannerController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  PageController _contentController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bannerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: PageView(
              controller: _bannerController,
              onPageChanged: (int value) {
                _contentController.animateToPage(value,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOut);
              },
              children: [
                MyPage1Widget(),
                MyPage2Widget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: PageView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _contentController,
              children: [
                MyPage1Widget(),
                MyPage2Widget(),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage1Widget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("Page 1"),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage2Widget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("Page 2"),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if there is a better solution than this.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AccountScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class AccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AccountScreenState createState() => _AccountScreenState();
}

class _AccountScreenState extends State<AccountScreen> {
  PageController _contentController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _contentController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      controller: _contentController,
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: [
        //They are different just to see different approaches
        MyPage3Widget(),
        MyPage4Widget(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyPage3Widget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 200),
        Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onHorizontalDragUpdate: (_) {}, //This does the trick
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Center(child: Text("Page 2")))),
        )
      ],
    )
    );
  }
}

class MyPage4Widget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(), //it will scroll only when dragging the AppBar as if it were your banner
      body: GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: (_) {}, //This does the trick
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Center(child: Text("Page 2"))
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Adding a GestureDetector to the body part you don't want the user to scroll with an empty gesture (onHorizontalDragUpdate because you don't want to drag horizontally) tricks the Gesture Arena to think that the gesture detector is the one that wants to do something. Use a Container with transparent color to fill all the available space (If I used only Center or Text it will just wrap that text, check the flutter inspector to see the whole area).

Advantages comparing your example:

- There is only one PageController
- The animation move smooth, when moving the banner the pageView moves with it